# MVC3 input submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, submit

I have an Index page in an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  The Index View of my Proposal Model contains an input submit button:

```
 <input  type="submit" name="Create" id="Create" value="Create New Proposal" style="width: 200px" />
```

When the button is clicked, I want to invoke the Create View on the Proposal Model.  However, I can't get any method in the Proposal Controller to fire when clicking on the "create New" input button.  Can I call the Index Post method?  The Proposal Create get method?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your submit button inside a `form` and an overloaded `ActionResult` in your controller which uses the `HttpPost` attribute.

Something like...

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(new MyViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
   // do stuff with model
}
```

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

That would render a form and post it to the Index action result in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an HTML Helper like `@Html.BeginForm`.  See here for clues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx

In your case try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Proposal")){

......
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a post method and then use this for displaying your View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "Controller", "FormMethod.Post"))
{   
  //your View code display
}
```