# Form post passes null model - .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using [this post as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968768/mvc3-input-submit)

I am trying to get the Model that I passed to the view to post back to the HttpPost method of the controller when the input is clicked. **However, the model, which in this case is just List, is null when it posts back.**

I have included my code for reference. This is just a project for testing random stuff out so I apologize for the crappy code.

I have the following View code: (showing the whole code for completness)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using TestApp.MyObjects
@model List<Contact>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show About", "About", new { id = "1" }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "contentDiv" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Contact", "Contact", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "contentDiv" })
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table>
        @foreach (Contact c in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button aboutnum0 = "@c.someValues[0]" aboutnum1 = "@c.someValues[1]" aboutnum2 = "@c.someValues[2]" class="nameButton">@c.name</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input value="@Model[0].name" />
    <input value="@Model[0].name" />
    <div id ="aboutContentDiv"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
    @ViewBag.myCoolValue
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#aboutContentDiv").empty();
        $("#aboutContentDiv").append($("<div></div>").load("Home/About/" + $(this).attr("aboutnum0")));
        $("#aboutContentDiv").append($("<div></div>").load("Home/About/" + $(this).attr("aboutnum1")));
        $("#aboutContentDiv").append($("<div></div>").load("Home/About/" + $(this).attr("aboutnum2")));
    });

</script>
```

The Following is my Comtroller Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.MyObjects;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.name = "Some Name";
            c.someValues = new List<string>();
            c.someValues.Add("1");
            c.someValues.Add("2");
            c.someValues.Add("3");
            Contact c1 = new Contact();
            c1.name = "Some Name1";
            c1.someValues = new List<string>();
            c1.someValues.Add("4");
            c1.someValues.Add("5");
            c1.someValues.Add("6");
            Contact c2 = new Contact();
            c2.name = "Some Name2";
            c2.someValues = new List<string>();
            c2.someValues.Add("7");
            c2.someValues.Add("8");
            c2.someValues.Add("9");
            List<Contact> clist = new List<Contact>();
            clist.Add(c);
            clist.Add(c1);
            clist.Add(c2);
            Session["myCoolValue"] = "Cool1";
            TempData["myCoolValue"] = "Cool2";
            return View(clist);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<Contact> contacts)
        {
            string name = contacts[0].name;
            return View("Index",contacts);
        }
        public PartialViewResult About(string id = "")
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            About a = new About();
            a.someValue = id + " _ modified by contoller";
            ViewBag.myCoolValue = "Cool";
            return PartialView("About",a);
        }

        public PartialViewResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return PartialView("Contact");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you planning to accept inputs for the model or do you just want to post it back? If you are planning to accept inputs, do you have a (partial) view for the contact model?

Comment: I often would have a partial view for the Contact model. I guess in this test senario I do not. I would think that it is not required I have a partial view for the Contact? For example you can see I put the first contact's name into an input. This should allow for editing and for me to see the edit on post back. Or am I not understand how this works?

Comment: the way you created the nested `@Model.name` looks right. Did you mean to create the input twice or is that cut-paste error?

Comment: @kralco626 if you intend to accept the list of contacts as an input, and not just only one of them, then you need to put it inside the loop. And make sure you "name" them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comment, you need something like this:

```
  // you can use foreach and have a counter variable or this
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    // you do not want to use a partial view so let's do it this way
    // put this in an appropriate place in your code
    // like inside a tr or div, it's up to you
    @Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i].name)

  }
```

Comment: So based on this answer, your saying that if I want MVC to update name in the model when the textbox value is changed I have to use TextboxFor as opposed to creating it through html like I did in my example.

Comment: Well it's easier to do it that way. But sure you can code the html yourself. The format would be: <input type="text" name="[i].name"/>. And you might also need the Id for each contact so be sure to add those too as hidden fields.